# SuiteScript Workflow Action-how to add error handling

Tags: error-handling, suitescript2.0

I have a workflow action script that is supposed to search for a string in an email message body (the string being for the document number--this is stored in a field with the id 'custevent_case_creation') and return the transaction record id.

The script:

```js
        /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
     * @param {Object} context
     */
    
    define(["N/search", "N/record"], function (search, record) {
      function onAction(context) {
        var recordObj = context.newRecord;
        var oc_number = recordObj.getValue({ fieldId: "custevent_case_creation" });
        var s = search
          .create({
            type: "salesorder",
            filters: [
              search.createFilter({
                name: "tranid",
                operator: search.Operator.IS,
                values: [oc_number],
              }),
            ],
            columns: ["internalid"],
          })
          .run()
          .getRange({
            start: 0,
            end: 1,
          });
        log.debug("result set", s[0].id);
    
        return s[0].id;
      }
    
      return {
        onAction: onAction,
      };
    });
```

This works as expected when there is a valid document number used in the email message.

However, there are two scenarios where that won't be the case:

1. there is no document number referenced in the original email (and therefore, the field "custevent_case_creation" will be blank)
2. the document number referenced is incorrect and there is no transaction with that document number in the system

I am trying to add some form of error handling to deal with these two scenarios though I can't find anything that works. Where should the error handling be in this script?
Should it be an if/else statement?

So far I have tried:

- adding if{s.length>0);
- adding a condition in the workflow itself so that the custom action from the workflow action script doesn't occur if the field for custevent_case_creation is blank
  -[image: workflow action UI]

The error message I am getting is:

```js
    org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from undefined (/SuiteScripts/sdf_ignore/Workflow Action Lookup SO.js#41)
```

EDIT:
The working code

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
     * @param {Object} context
     */
    
    define(["N/search", "N/record"], function (search, record) {
      function onAction(context) {
        try {
          var recordObj = context.newRecord;
          var oc_number = recordObj.getValue({
            fieldId: "custevent_case_creation",
          });
          var s = search
            .create({
              type: "salesorder",
              filters: [
                search.createFilter({
                  name: "tranid",
                  operator: search.Operator.IS,
                  values: [oc_number],
                }),
              ],
              columns: ["internalid"],
            })
            .run()
            .getRange({
              start: 0,
              end: 1,
            });
          log.debug("result set", s[0].id);
    
          return s[0].id;
        } catch (error) {
          log.debug(
            error.name,
            "recordObjId: " +
              recordObj.id +
              ", oc_number:" +
              oc_number +
              ", message: " +
              error.message
          );
        }
      }
    
      return {
        onAction: onAction,
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the contents of you onAction function with try/catch.  More info on try/catch can be found [here on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp).

```
try {
    //your working code for onAction function
    var recordObj = context.newRecord;
    var oc_number = recordObj.getValue({ fieldId: "custevent_case_creation" });
    var s = search.create({
        type: "salesorder",
        filters: [
          search.createFilter({
            name: "tranid",
            operator: search.Operator.IS,
            values: [oc_number]
          })
        ],
        columns: ["internalid"]
      })run().getRange({
        start: 0,
        end: 1,
      });
    log.debug("result set", s[0].id);

    return s[0].id;
} catch(e){
    log.debug(e.name,'recordObjId: '+ recordObj.id +', oc_number:'+ oc_number +', message: ' + e.message); //if e.name is empty try e.title
    //you can add additional steps here if desired, i.e. send an email, display an alert, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martha!. I edited the catch section so that it says error .(instead of e.), but other than that, the code worked perfectly

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad it worked!